# Выработка сеансового ключа через OpenSSL

Tags: c, криптография, openssl, сокеты

Друзья! Помогите пожалуйста. Пытаюсь выработать общий ключ по протоколу Диффи-Хеллмана между клиентом и сервером (простеньким, это для учебы). Сколько не пробовал, общий ключ одинаковый не получается. Параметры p и g пересылаю через TCP, точно так же и публичные ключи. Ошибок никаких нет, просто получаются разные значения.

**Это клиент**

```
    DH *dh = DH_new(); //инициализируем структуру параметров Diffie-Hellman
    DH_generate_parameters_ex(dh, 128, 5, NULL); //генерируем p (256 битов) и g (число р потом перезапишем)
    DH_generate_key(dh); // генерируем публичный и приватный ключ
    unsigned char *recv_buf = (unsigned char*) malloc(1000); //буфер приема данных
    memset(recv_buf, 0, 1000);
    unsigned char *shared_key; //общий ключ
    shared_key = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*(DH_size(dh)));


//////Принимаем число p/////////////////////////////////
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) malloc(1000);//
    memset(p, 0, 1000);                               //
    while(1)                                          //
        {                                             //
            if(recv(sd, recv_buf, 1000, 0))           //
            {                                         //
                break;                                //
            }                                         //
            sleep(1);                                 //
        }                                             //
    strncpy(p, recv_buf, strlen(recv_buf)+1);           //
    BIGNUM* temp_p = BN_new();                        //
    int a = BN_hex2bn(&temp_p, p);                    //
    dh->p = temp_p;                                   //
    memset(recv_buf, 0, 1000);                        //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////Принимаем число g/////////////////////////////////
    unsigned char *g = (unsigned char *) malloc(1000);//
    memset(g, 0, 1000);                               //
    while(1)                                          //
        {                                             //
            if(recv(sd, recv_buf, 1000, 0))           //
            {                                         //
                break;                                //
            }                                         //
            sleep(1);                                 //
        }                                             //
    strncpy(g, recv_buf, strlen(recv_buf)+1);           //
    BIGNUM* temp_g = BN_new();                        //
    a = BN_hex2bn(&temp_g, g);                    //
    dh->g = temp_g;                                   //
    memset(recv_buf, 0, 1000);                        //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////Принимаем публичный ключ сервера//////////////////////////////
    unsigned char *server_pub_key = (unsigned char*) malloc(1000);//
    memset(server_pub_key, 0, 1000);                              //
    while(1)                                                      //
        {                                                         //
            if(recv(sd, recv_buf, 1000, 0))                       //
            {                                                     //
                break;                                            //
            }                                                     //
            sleep(1);                                             //
        }                                                         //
    strncpy(server_pub_key, recv_buf, strlen(recv_buf)+1);         //
    memset(recv_buf, 0, 1000);                                    //
    BIGNUM* server_pubkey_bignum = NULL;                          //
    a = BN_hex2bn(&server_pubkey_bignum, server_pub_key);         //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////Отправляем свой публичный ключ////////////////////////////////
    unsigned char *pub_key = (unsigned char*) malloc(1000);       //
    memset(pub_key, 0, 1000);                                     //
    pub_key = BN_bn2hex(dh->pub_key);                             //                       
    while(1)                                                      //
    {                                                             //
    if(send(sd, pub_key, strlen(pub_key)+1, 0))                                 //
        {                                                         //
            sleep(1);                                             //
            break;                                                //
        }                                                         //
    }                                                             //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////Вычисляем сеансовый ключ/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if(DH_compute_key(shared_key, server_pubkey_bignum, dh))
    {
        //Переменные для MD5///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        unsigned char *md5_key;//MD5 - ключ                                      //
        md5_key = (unsigned char*) malloc(1000);                                 //
        memset(md5_key, 0, 1000);                                                //
        size_t len_of_sh_k = strlen(shared_key);//Длина DH-ключа                 //
        unsigned char *md5_res = (unsigned char*) malloc(1000);                  //
        memset(md5_res, 0, 1000);                                                //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  


        //Считаем MD5//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        md5_res = MD5(shared_key, len_of_sh_k, md5_key);//делаем ключ 128 бит    //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        while(1)
        {
            memset(recv_buf,0,1000);
            if(recv(sd, recv_buf, 1000, 0))
            {
                break;
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
        char* md5_serv = (char*)malloc(1000);
        memset(md5_serv,0,1000);
        strncpy(md5_serv, recv_buf, strlen(recv_buf)+1);
        while(1)
        {
            memset(recv_buf,0,1000);
            if(recv(sd, recv_buf, 1000, 0))
            {
                break;
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
        char* sh_k = (char*)malloc(1000);
        memset(sh_k,0,1000);
        strncpy(sh_k, recv_buf, strlen(recv_buf)+1);
        printf("\nmd5_key1 = %s\nmd5_key2 = %s\nмой sh_k = %s len = %d\nserv sh_k = %s len = %d", md5_res, md5_serv, shared_key, strlen(shared_key), sh_k, strlen(sh_k));
    }
    close(sd);
    getchar();
```

**Это сервер**

```
 //сначала сгенерируем параметры диффи-хеллмана
    DH *dh = DH_new(); //инициализируем структуру параметров
    DH_generate_parameters_ex(dh, 128, 5, NULL); //генерируем p (256 битов) и g
    DH_generate_key(dh); // генерируем публичный и приватный ключ
    unsigned char *shared_key; //общий ключ
    shared_key = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*(DH_size(dh)));


//////Отправляем число p/////////////////////////////////
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) malloc(1000); //
    memset(p, 0, 1000);                                //
    p = BN_bn2hex(dh->p);                              //
    while(1)                                           //
    {                                                  // 
        if(send(cd, p, strlen(p)+1, 0))              //
        {
            sleep(1);                                  //
            break;                                     //
        }                                              //
    }                                                  //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////Отправляем число g/////////////////////////////////
    unsigned char *g = (unsigned char *) malloc(1000); //
    memset(g, 0, 1000);                                //
    g = BN_bn2hex(dh->g);                              //
    while(1)                                           //
    {                                                  // 
        if(send(cd, g, strlen(g)+1, 0))              //
        {
            sleep(1);                                  //
            break;                                     //
        }                                              //
    }                                                  //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////Определяем буфер приема данных//////////////////////////    
    unsigned char *recv_buf = (unsigned char*) malloc(1000);//
    memset(recv_buf, 0, 1000);                              //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////Отправляем публичный ключ сервера//////////////////////
    unsigned char *pub_key = (unsigned char*) malloc(1000);//
    memset(pub_key, 0, 1000);                              //
    pub_key = BN_bn2hex(dh->pub_key);                      //
    while(1)                                               //
    {                                                      //
        if(send(cd, pub_key, strlen(pub_key)+1, 0))        //
        {
            sleep(1);                                      //
            break;                                         //
        }                                                  //
    }                                                      //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////Принимаем публичный ключ клиента/////////////////////////////////
    unsigned char* client_pubkey_hex = (unsigned char*) malloc(1000);//
    memset(client_pubkey_hex, 0, 1000);                              //
    memset(recv_buf, 0, 1000);                                       //
    while(1)                                                         //
    {                                                                //
        if(recv(cd, recv_buf, 1000, 0))                              //
        {                                                            //
            break;                                                   //        
        }
        sleep(1);                                                    //
    }                                                                //
    strncpy(client_pubkey_hex, recv_buf, strlen(recv_buf)+1);           //
    memset(recv_buf, 0, 1000);                                       //
    BIGNUM* client_pubkey_bignum;                         //
    int a = BN_hex2bn(&client_pubkey_bignum, client_pubkey_hex);     //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    


//////Вычисляем сеансовый ключ/////////////////////////////////////////
    if(DH_compute_key(shared_key, client_pubkey_bignum, dh))
    {
        //Переменные для MD5///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        unsigned char *md5_key;//MD5 - ключ                                      //
        md5_key = (unsigned char*) malloc(1000);                                 //
        memset(md5_key, 0, 1000);                                                //
        size_t len_of_sh_k = strlen(shared_key);//Длина DH-ключа                 //
        unsigned char *md5_res = (unsigned char*) malloc(1000);                  //
        memset(md5_res, 0, 1000);                                                //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        //Считаем MD5//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        md5_res = MD5(shared_key, len_of_sh_k, md5_key);//делаем ключ 128 бит    //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        while(1)
        {
        if(send(cd, md5_key, strlen(md5_key)+1, 0))
            {
                sleep(1);
                break;
            }
        }

        while(1)
        {
        if(send(cd, shared_key, strlen(shared_key)+1, 0))
            {
                sleep(1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Далее общий ключ и MD5 отправляю просто, чтобы сверить на клиенте. Ломаю голову уже 3 дня, ничего не помогает

Comment: опенссл сама может обменяться ключами по tls

Comment: Да я понимаю, конечно, но хотелось бы самому написать

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется, у вас будут получаться разные ключи! Ведь клиент и сервер используют РАЗНЫЕ группы для генерации ключей. Каждый раз, когда программа вызывает `DH_generate_parameters_ex` генерируется новый набор параметров.

Поэтому вызов функции `DH_generate_parameters_ex` в клиенте сгенерирует одно простое число, а в сервере - другое. Для проверки позапускайте вот эту простенькую программу, которая генерирует параметры и печатает их:

```
#include <openssl/dh.h>

int main() {
    DH *dh = DH_new();
    DH_generate_parameters_ex(dh, 128, 5, NULL);
    DHparams_print_fp(stdout, dh);
    return 0;
}
```

Вы увидите, что каждый раз будет генерироваться новый набор параметров.

Вам не нужно вызывать в клиенте `DH_generate_parameters_ex`, достаточно `DH_new`. Соответственно, генерировать ключи в клиенте только после того, как получены P и G от сервера, то есть там, где у вас комментарий `//Принимаем публичный ключ сервера`.

Эту же задачу можно решить ещё двумя способами.

План А.
Можно пересылать между сервером и клиентом не числа `p` и `g`, а сериализованное представление параметров DH сервера. Там сразу будет и `p`, и `g`.

Генерация сериализованного представления: функция `i2d_DHparams`
Создание параметров из сериализованного представления: функция `d2i_DHparams`

План Б.
Но самый простой способ, ИМХО, заранее договориться клиенту и серверу, какую группу они будут использовать. То есть один раз сгенерировать сериализованное представление, а затем его использовать и в клиенте, и в сервере.

Например, вот такая сериализация соответствует DH с простым числом `00:b7:92:27:f2:68:28:e8:4e:ce:2e:f4:21:40:94:81:63` и генератором `5`:

```
#include <openssl/dh.h>

int main() {
    // expected prime: 00:b7:92:27:f2:68:28:e8:4e:ce:2e:f4:21:40:94:81:63
    unsigned char serialized_params[] = { 0x30, 0x16, 0x02, 0x11, 0x00, 0xb7, 0x92, 0x27, 0xf2, 0x68, 0x28, 0xe8, 0x4e, 0xce, 0x2e, 0xf4, 0x21, 0x40, 0x94, 0x81, 0x63, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05};
    unsigned char *buf = serialized_params;
    DH *dh_restored = d2i_DHparams(NULL, &buf, sizeof(serialized_params));
    DHparams_print_fp(stdout, dh_restored);

    return 0;
}
```

Вот что эта программа печатает:

```
    DH Parameters: (128 bit)
        prime:
            00:b7:92:27:f2:68:28:e8:4e:ce:2e:f4:21:40:94:
            81:63
        generator: 5 (0x5)
```

Как сгенерировать сериализованное представление параметров DH:

```
#include <openssl/dh.h>

int main() {
    DH *dh = DH_new();
    DH_generate_parameters_ex(dh, 128, 5, NULL);
    DHparams_print_fp(stdout, dh);

    unsigned char * param_buf = NULL;
    int len;
    len = i2d_DHparams(dh, &param_buf);
    printf("Len %d: [", len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { printf("0x%02x, ", param_buf[i]); }
    printf("]\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Вот пример вывода этой программы:

```
    DH Parameters: (128 bit)
        prime:
            00:b1:a3:58:c2:2f:66:21:d4:53:c9:71:84:eb:f6:
            b5:33
        generator: 5 (0x5)
Len 24: [0x30, 0x16, 0x02, 0x11, 0x00, 0xb1, 0xa3, 0x58, 0xc2, 0x2f, 0x66, 0x21, 0xd4, 0x53, 0xc9, 0x71, 0x84, 0xeb, 0xf6, 0xb5, 0x33, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05, ]
```

Если вы замените в предыдущей программе инциализатор константы `serialized_params` на `{0x30, 0x16, 0x02, 0x11, 0x00, 0xb1, 0xa3, 0x58, 0xc2, 0x2f, 0x66, 0x21, 0xd4, 0x53, 0xc9, 0x71, 0x84, 0xeb, 0xf6, 0xb5, 0x33, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05}`, то вы получите DH с простым числом `00:b1:a3:58:c2:2f:66:21:d4:53:c9:71:84:eb:f6:b5:33` и генератором `5`.

Ну и тому подобное.